# Master page showing unexpectedly

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

When I am clicking on the upload button in document web, inside that the section master page is showing (which should not).

How to remove this either in SharePoint designer or SharePoint 2013 itself?

Also, the site settings is showing up on home page (but it should show in a separate new page).

Screeshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a custom master page that is missing much of the core structure of a master page. In particular, an out of the box master page responds to a Query String value of "?IsDlg=1" to control if master page content is displayed in SharePoint dialog boxes along with primary page content.

To see this, go to a site without this custom master page and visit a list or library page. Edit the URL and, if there's no Query String (i.e. no "?" in the URL, add "?IsDlg=1" (no quotes), or if there is a query string add "&IsDlg=1" (no quotes). Notice the difference in the displayed content.

Something is missing from your custom master page. Either the lack of standard CSS classes or missing JavaScript references.

Can you reset the master page back to one of the out of the box master pages and check to see if everything is now working.

As the the Site Settings, someone must of added an IFRAME or a Page Viewer web part to the home page and set the URL to the Site Settings page.

Comment: I followed what you have mentioned in second paragraph. I appended ?IsDlg=1 only list and libraries(when i change to seattle master page) but if i change to my custom master page my custom master page is also showing along with the list and libraries. How to change the url so that i can append ?IsDlg=1 at the end?

Comment: You will need to take a look at the custom master page and see what was removed that a default master page has. Most likely it's CSS class names or JavaScript that changes the class names